# How to set up real time updates in Facebook

Tags: facebook

To use facebook payments you need to have a realtime update callback set. Facebook references this and describes it here

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/

however there is nowhere in the app settings to set up that callback URL. There used to be a few months ago but now it's gone. What's the appropriate way to retrieve data about payments made?

Answer (score 0):

The settings screen in the Facebook App details seems to be gone... But you can subscribe via the Graph API as described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/realtimeupdates/#subscribingviagraphapi